# How to get windows 10 display language programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-10, system, locale

I've been stuck on this for hours. I googled some, and found this:

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
```

and this:

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0];
```

But both are referencing English language. Because English is the first one of my system language list. But English is not the Display Language of my system, while Chinese is.

So is there a way to get the display language of windows system programmatically?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hmm, there is no "system language list".   There is a list of language preferences (has the Move Up and Move Down commands).  If English is the first on that list then that's your preference and what you get from GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0].  Maybe you ought to change your preferences, click Move Up/Down to rearrange that list, maybe you want to use Windows.Globalization.Language.CurrentInputMethodLanguageTag instead.

Comment: Sorry for the inappropriate description, I mean exactly a list of language preferences. I've tried to make English the default language, but it won't work. Windows display language is still Chinese, so my system still showing Chinese. I googled a little bit, and it seems i'm using Windows 10 Single language Chinese Edition, and in that case i can only use one language.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**System.Globalization.CultureInfo**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
            var ci = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;

            Console.WriteLine("Default Language Info:");
            Console.WriteLine("* Name: {0}", ci.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("* Display Name: {0}", ci.DisplayName);
            Console.WriteLine("* English Name: {0}", ci.EnglishName);
            Console.WriteLine("* 2-letter ISO Name: {0}", ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
            Console.WriteLine("* 3-letter ISO Name: {0}", ci.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName);
            Console.WriteLine("* 3-letter Win32 API Name: {0}", ci.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName);
```

## **WinRT**

For WinRT I guess you have to use [**ApplicationLanguages APIs**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh972395.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), but I cannot provide you code as I am not able to test since I am running another version ofwin.

Comment: Thank you for your quickly reply, @Sid. But property InstalledUICulture is not available in my code. My code is under Windows Runtime which cannot reference features in .Net Framework? I'm not sure, though.Sorry, I forgot to mention it. I've tried that. Is there another way??

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I didn't make it to work. You know what? The Microsoft's Store app is not using the display language, and it uses the first one of the list of language preferences. So I'm using it too. I don't need to stuck on this display language thing. But I'll leave the question here, in case someone's interest. Thanks again for your advice and sorry for the late reply(working on something else).